# How to pass a var for a view.init in fullScreenCover?

Tags: swiftui

I have a view presented with fullScreenCover. I pass a bunch of variables, all good but ONE of them (input) is not passing/updating. I've noticed the value always retains the first input var from the first fullScreenCover call from the parent view (I call fullscreencover multiple times)

How to pass a var for a view.init in fullScreenCover?

full screen initialization

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $likeModal, content: {
                                                    LikeScreenModalView.init(likeModalShown: $likeModal, indexHere: $index, input: model.matches[index].imageUrl1!, receiver: model.matches[index].name, type: "Image", question: "", receiverImage: model.matches[index].imageUrl1!, picNumber: 1)
                                                        .environmentObject(ChatsViewModel())
                                                        .environmentObject(ContentModel())
                                                })
```

```
struct LikeScreenModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var chatModel: ChatsViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentModel
    
    
    @Binding var likeModalShown : Bool
    @Binding var indexHere: Int
    
    @State var opener: String = ""
    @State public var input : String
    var receiver: String
    var type: String
    var question: String
    var receiverImage: String
    var picNumber: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //object reference for opener
            if type == "Image" {
                WebImage(url: URL(string: input))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(10)
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Text(input)
                }
            }
            
            
            TextField("Say something nice", text: $opener).font(.title)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
            
            Button {
                //write in firebase a new conversation
                let user = UserService.shared.user
                print(user.id)
                
                //move to next match
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if indexHere == model.matches.count-1 {
                        //go back to first match
                        indexHere = 0
                    } else {
                        indexHere += 1
                    }
                }

                
                likeModalShown.toggle() //flip to false
                
                chatModel.startConversation(receiver: receiver, message: opener, receiverImg: receiverImage)
                
                
            } label: {
                Text("Send Message")
            }.padding()
            
            Button("I chickened out...") {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }.padding()
            
            
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use binding or the init that uses item

Comment: I feel embarrassed! thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

`@State public var input : String`

it may works